# Warning from defining same property name from parent class

Tags: objective-c

If a child class define the same property name override to parent class, a warning is supposed to occur:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'homeInt'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

If I have a subclass of CALayer and define a property called 'delegate', I'll receive this warning. 
However, If I have a subclass of UIView and define a property called 'maskView', there is no warning.

How come there is such a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, If a child class define the same property name override to parent class:

Do like this:

```
@implementation yourClass

@dynamic homeInt;
```

if not,

then you should rename the property.

See this also:

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/660